# Android java loop through object list

Tags: java, android, json, list, object

My code connects to an Api, takes all Json values and stores them all in a object list `resultClass`. How I loop through the list and display all name properties of the objects?

This is the code I am using. The JSON values are sent with the method call as parameter with name `object`. Then loops and takes all objects and stores them in a list.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
        Log.i("gw2Log", "Json Response" + object);

        resultClass resultClass = new resultClass();

        try {
            resultClass.setCount(object.getInt("count"));
            resultClass.setPage(object.getInt("page"));
            resultClass.setLast_page(object.getInt("last_page"));
            resultClass.setTotal(object.getInt("total"));
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray(object.getString("results"));

            for (int i = 0; i < resultClass.getTotal(); i++) {
                JSONObject resultsObject = list.getJSONObject(i);

                resultClass.setData_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("data_id"));
                resultClass.setName(resultsObject
                        .getString("name"));
                resultClass.setRarity(resultsObject
                        .getInt("rarity"));
                resultClass.setRestriction_level(resultsObject
                        .getInt("restriction_level"));
                resultClass.setImg(resultsObject
                        .getString("img"));
                resultClass.setType_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("type_id"));
                resultClass.setSub_type_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sub_type_id"));
                resultClass.setPrice_last_changed(resultsObject
                        .getString("price_last_changed"));
                resultClass.setMax_offer_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("max_offer_unit_price"));
                resultClass.setMin_sale_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("min_sale_unit_price"));
                resultClass.setOffer_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_availability"));
                resultClass.setSale_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_availability"));
                resultClass.setSale_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_price_change_last_hour"));
                resultClass.setOffer_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_price_change_last_hour"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < resultClass.total; i++) {
            Log.i("gw2Log", resultClass.name[i]);
        }
    }
```

This is the Json response i am logging

```
Json Response{"total":6,"last_page":1,"results":[{"sale_availability":0,"offer_availability":0,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/01D07FABAE26C0E5240892B00DA7AF90AB0EA022\/455828.png","rarity":7,"type_id":16,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":0,"data_id":19648,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:23:48 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Gift of Twilight","min_sale_unit_price":0,"restriction_level":0,"sub_type_id":0},{"sale_availability":0,"offer_availability":0,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/CE3AF0B7B9BB6244726779F5B6A930541BA6C15F\/456031.png","rarity":5,"type_id":18,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":0,"data_id":49191,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:23:48 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Twilight","min_sale_unit_price":0,"restriction_level":80,"sub_type_id":6},{"sale_availability":23,"offer_availability":20643,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/CE3AF0B7B9BB6244726779F5B6A930541BA6C15F\/456031.png","rarity":7,"type_id":18,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":27500000,"data_id":30704,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:17:57 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Twilight","min_sale_unit_price":31959998,"restriction_level":80,"sub_type_id":6},{"sale_availability":0,"offer_availability":0,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/D04EF6FDE3DBC26E7BB109EB4F52057FEAD8619E\/699325.png","rarity":1,"type_id":4,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":0,"data_id":65578,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:23:48 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Twilight Arbor Armor Box","min_sale_unit_price":0,"restriction_level":0,"sub_type_id":0},{"sale_availability":0,"offer_availability":0,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/666209104CCB024D53359C0EA0A299076E610771\/65704.png","rarity":1,"type_id":4,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":0,"data_id":65577,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:23:48 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Twilight Arbor Token Loot Box","min_sale_unit_price":0,"restriction_level":0,"sub_type_id":0},{"sale_availability":0,"offer_availability":0,"img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/2626184EDDC254B4F7634A04F878062C6B2AF20D\/780372.png","rarity":1,"type_id":4,"sale_price_change_last_hour":0,"max_offer_unit_price":0,"data_id":65579,"price_last_changed":"2015-04-20 20:23:48 UTC","offer_price_change_last_hour":0,"name":"Twilight Arbor Weapons Box","min_sale_unit_price":0,"restriction_level":0,"sub_type_id":0}],"count":6,"page":1}
```

When digging around for a solution and checking the actual error it says it expects and array but a string is given `Log.i("gw2Log", resultClass.name[i]);`

When I loop through this Log call `Log.i("gw2Log", resultClass.name);` it displays the last objects name property the amount it loops.

EDIT:
On request to include my resultClass.java:

```
public class resultClass {

    public int data_id;
    public String name;
    public int rarity;
    public int restriction_level;
    public String img;
    public int type_id;
    public int sub_type_id;
    public String price_last_changed;
    public int max_offer_unit_price;
    public int min_sale_unit_price;
    public int offer_availability;
    public int sale_availability;
    public int sale_price_change_last_hour;
    public int offer_price_change_last_hour;

    public int count;
    public int page;
    public int last_page;
    public int total;

    public int getData_id() {
        return data_id;
    }

    public void setData_id(int data_id) {
        this.data_id = data_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRarity() {
        return rarity;
    }

    public void setRarity(int rarity) {
        this.rarity = rarity;
    }

    public int getRestriction_level() {
        return restriction_level;
    }

    public void setRestriction_level(int restriction_level) {
        this.restriction_level = restriction_level;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int getType_id() {
        return type_id;
    }

    public void setType_id(int type_id) {
        this.type_id = type_id;
    }

    public int getSub_type_id() {
        return sub_type_id;
    }

    public void setSub_type_id(int sub_type_id) {
        this.sub_type_id = sub_type_id;
    }

    public String getPrice_last_changed() {
        return price_last_changed;
    }

    public void setPrice_last_changed(String price_last_changed) {
        this.price_last_changed = price_last_changed;
    }

    public int getMax_offer_unit_price() {
        return max_offer_unit_price;
    }

    public void setMax_offer_unit_price(int max_offer_unit_price) {
        this.max_offer_unit_price = max_offer_unit_price;
    }

    public int getMin_sale_unit_price() {
        return min_sale_unit_price;
    }

    public void setMin_sale_unit_price(int min_sale_unit_price) {
        this.min_sale_unit_price = min_sale_unit_price;
    }

    public int getOffer_availability() {
        return offer_availability;
    }

    public void setOffer_availability(int offer_availability) {
        this.offer_availability = offer_availability;
    }

    public int getSale_availability() {
        return sale_availability;
    }

    public void setSale_availability(int sale_availability) {
        this.sale_availability = sale_availability;
    }

    public int getSale_price_change_last_hour() {
        return sale_price_change_last_hour;
    }

    public void setSale_price_change_last_hour(int sale_price_change_last_hour) {
        this.sale_price_change_last_hour = sale_price_change_last_hour;
    }

    public int getOffer_price_change_last_hour() {
        return offer_price_change_last_hour;
    }

    public void setOffer_price_change_last_hour(int offer_price_change_last_hour) {
        this.offer_price_change_last_hour = offer_price_change_last_hour;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getLast_page() {
        return last_page;
    }

    public void setLast_page(int last_page) {
        this.last_page = last_page;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you are overwriting resultClass on every loop. can you post the resultClass here?

Comment: @TomerShemesh I have edited my post and included the `resultClass.java`

Comment: Yea you are indeed erasing everything on each loop. try creating an arrayList and creating multiple modals to map to

Comment: @TomerShemesh Could you help me out? I dont know where to start or how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

first make a new object something like MyObject

```
public class MyObject {

public int data_id;
public String name;
public int rarity;
public int restriction_level;
public String img;
public int type_id;
public int sub_type_id;
public String price_last_changed;
public int max_offer_unit_price;
public int min_sale_unit_price;
public int offer_availability;
public int sale_availability;
public int sale_price_change_last_hour;
public int offer_price_change_last_hour;

public int getData_id() {
    return data_id;
}

public void setData_id(int data_id) {
    this.data_id = data_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getRarity() {
    return rarity;
}

public void setRarity(int rarity) {
    this.rarity = rarity;
}

public int getRestriction_level() {
    return restriction_level;
}

public void setRestriction_level(int restriction_level) {
    this.restriction_level = restriction_level;
}

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public int getType_id() {
    return type_id;
}

public void setType_id(int type_id) {
    this.type_id = type_id;
}

public int getSub_type_id() {
    return sub_type_id;
}

public void setSub_type_id(int sub_type_id) {
    this.sub_type_id = sub_type_id;
}

public String getPrice_last_changed() {
    return price_last_changed;
}

public void setPrice_last_changed(String price_last_changed) {
    this.price_last_changed = price_last_changed;
}

public int getMax_offer_unit_price() {
    return max_offer_unit_price;
}

public void setMax_offer_unit_price(int max_offer_unit_price) {
    this.max_offer_unit_price = max_offer_unit_price;
}

public int getMin_sale_unit_price() {
    return min_sale_unit_price;
}

public void setMin_sale_unit_price(int min_sale_unit_price) {
    this.min_sale_unit_price = min_sale_unit_price;
}

public int getOffer_availability() {
    return offer_availability;
}

public void setOffer_availability(int offer_availability) {
    this.offer_availability = offer_availability;
}

public int getSale_availability() {
    return sale_availability;
}

public void setSale_availability(int sale_availability) {
    this.sale_availability = sale_availability;
}

public int getSale_price_change_last_hour() {
    return sale_price_change_last_hour;
}

public void setSale_price_change_last_hour(int sale_price_change_last_hour) {
    this.sale_price_change_last_hour = sale_price_change_last_hour;
}

public int getOffer_price_change_last_hour() {
    return offer_price_change_last_hour;
}

public void setOffer_price_change_last_hour(int offer_price_change_last_hour) {
    this.offer_price_change_last_hour = offer_price_change_last_hour;
}
}
```

then make your resultClass look like this

public class resultClass {

```
public int count;
public int page;
public int last_page;
public int total;
public ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList();

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public int getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(int page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public int getLast_page() {
    return last_page;
}

public void setLast_page(int last_page) {
    this.last_page = last_page;
}

public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public MyObject getObject(int pos){
    return myObjects.get(pos);
}
public void addObject(MyObject object)
{
    myObjects.add(object);
}
}
```

then your response should be something like this

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
    Log.i("gw2Log", "Json Response" + object);

    resultClass resultClass = new resultClass();

    try {
        resultClass.setCount(object.getInt("count"));
        resultClass.setPage(object.getInt("page"));
        resultClass.setLast_page(object.getInt("last_page"));
        resultClass.setTotal(object.getInt("total"));
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray(object.getString("results"));

        for (int i = 0; i < resultClass.getTotal(); i++) {
            JSONObject resultsObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
            MyObject temp = new MyObject();
            temp.setData_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("data_id"));
            temp.setName(resultsObject
                    .getString("name"));
            temp.setRarity(resultsObject
                    .getInt("rarity"));
            temp.setRestriction_level(resultsObject
                    .getInt("restriction_level"));
            temp.setImg(resultsObject
                    .getString("img"));
            temp.setType_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("type_id"));
            temp.setSub_type_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sub_type_id"));
            temp.setPrice_last_changed(resultsObject
                    .getString("price_last_changed"));
            temp.setMax_offer_unit_price(resultsObject
                    .getInt("max_offer_unit_price"));
            temp.setMin_sale_unit_price(resultsObject
                    .getInt("min_sale_unit_price"));
            temp.setOffer_availability(resultsObject
                    .getInt("offer_availability"));
            temp.setSale_availability(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sale_availability"));
            temp.setSale_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sale_price_change_last_hour"));
            temp.setOffer_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                    .getInt("offer_price_change_last_hour"));
            resultClass.addObject(temp);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < resultClass.total; i++) {
        Log.i("gw2Log", resultClass.getObject(i).name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly and I finally understand the problem aswell. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code. You wanted to use table of objects, but you created just single object. Create arrayList of your resultClass and then use simplier 'for' for your list

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
    Log.i("gw2Log", "Json Response" + object);

    List<resultClass> resultClassList = new ArrayList<resultClass>();
    resultClass resultClass = new resultClass();

    try {
        resultClass.setCount(object.getInt("count"));
        resultClass.setPage(object.getInt("page"));
        resultClass.setLast_page(object.getInt("last_page"));
        resultClass.setTotal(object.getInt("total"));
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray(object.getString("results"));

        for (int i = 0; i < resultClass.getTotal(); i++) {
            JSONObject resultsObject = list.getJSONObject(i);

            resultClass.setData_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("data_id"));
            resultClass.setName(resultsObject
                    .getString("name"));
            resultClass.setRarity(resultsObject
                    .getInt("rarity"));
            resultClass.setRestriction_level(resultsObject
                    .getInt("restriction_level"));
            resultClass.setImg(resultsObject
                    .getString("img"));
            resultClass.setType_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("type_id"));
            resultClass.setSub_type_id(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sub_type_id"));
            resultClass.setPrice_last_changed(resultsObject
                    .getString("price_last_changed"));
            resultClass.setMax_offer_unit_price(resultsObject
                    .getInt("max_offer_unit_price"));
            resultClass.setMin_sale_unit_price(resultsObject
                    .getInt("min_sale_unit_price"));
            resultClass.setOffer_availability(resultsObject
                    .getInt("offer_availability"));
            resultClass.setSale_availability(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sale_availability"));
            resultClass.setSale_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                    .getInt("sale_price_change_last_hour"));
            resultClass.setOffer_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                    .getInt("offer_price_change_last_hour"));
            resultClassList.add(resultClass);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(resultClass result : resultClassList) {
        Log.i("gw2Log", result.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm pretty sure of several things:

Tomer Shemesh is right, you are overriding your `resultClass` object on every iteration.

You wanna make arrays out of your normal variables in the `resultClass` so you can actually store more than one Item.

About that error you're getting:

It occurs in the lower for loop, where you want to log the names, right?

`resultClass.name`is a String variable, it holds exactly one string of characters. You are trying to get a string out of an array by saying something like `resultClass.name[i]`. For that to work youu need to decrlare it as a string array, holding several string like `public String[] name;`, and in the constructor initialize it with a given capactiy like `name = new String[cap];`. Or you use an `ArrayList<String>` instead, which grows dynmically, but uses own getters and setters instead of the easy name[index] functions of an array.

Sorry, but I don't really want to write the right code here, as pretty much the whole thing needs to be rewritten, I hope this will help you rewrite it yourself though.

Comment: haha you are very right. fortunately i am bored and have done the boring writing out for you!